# javascript & jquery optimization question

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a website that's being localized through JavaScript, however... I have alot of pages and in each page there are alot of text inputs items, I am using this plugin

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

to apply watermark on my inputs, now I just need guides for better performance.

1. Shall all watermarks be in one javascript file, or each page shall have it's own watermarks in it's own javascript file?
2. Shall i create one JavaScript file having all the system `$(object).watermark()` (I am choosing objects by classes), or each page with it's own JavaScript file must contain the jQuery watermark line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General: normally you would have page specific things in a page specific javascript.

Your Problem;
assuming your html looks something like this;

```
<input type='text' name='bla'></input>
```

You could rewrite it to read;

```
<input type='text' name='email' class='watermark' data-watertype='email'></input>
```

You could apply a single javascript snippet and inlcude it throughout the page;

```
    var texts={ "email":"Please enter a valid email address", .... },
        elems=jQuery("input.watermark"),
        elem,
        watermarkType;

    elems.each(function(i,elem){
        elem=jQuery(elem);
        watermarkType = texts[ elem.attr("data-watertype") ] || "";
        if (watermarkType.length!==0){
            //apply the watermark
            elem.watermark(watermarkType);
        }
    }
//this isn't tested but should work as expected!
```

thus resolving the need of having a specific javascript for each page to apply the watermarks

Comment: the problem is not how to do the watermark thing , I've already done it...the question is only performance question , shall i use one generic javascript file for all my pages or one file for each page? –

Comment: the problem is not how to do the watermark thing , I've already done it...the question is only performance question , shall i use one generic javascript file for all my pages or one file for each page?

Comment: ?!then, I don't understand what your question is. As I said on the top of my post; "normally you would have page specific things in a page specific javascript"
And I showed you a way, how you can handle ALL Watermarks accross ALL your pages with one single small file (which itself has to be on every page)
Performance wise, having one single javascript file per page is the smartest way to go, while contatenating all javascript files into one single file (but only for javascript used on every page -> (will be cached by the user) ) and only add other really page specific jsfiles "by hand".Helped?

Comment: I don't think it's wise to *ever* have any content kept in your JS files. You mentioned that these were localised, therefore I'd store the data in an XML or JSON document, that way your code is reusable and you won't have to edit lots of JS files for a small update.

Comment: @Ahmed, you are absolutely correct, but I'm not going to program a whole i18n site to demonstrate the idea :) wrapped in a closure/module "var mystuff={}" you could load a language specific js file that sets "mystuff.texts={...}" thus letting the code stay very generic while adding language support very easy.

Comment: Ok, then it shouldn't really have any performance issues. If you think about it: loading a localised XML or JSON file is more intensive than having the language hash all ready written in the code.

Comment: @Ahmed, again, you are correct :) but only for the first request of the user! After the first request, every additional request makes the user download his language specific information again. Putting it in an external file lets the user cache the information and thus, your only creating 'bad performance' for the initial visit (we are talking here about ~50ms). But after that, the information will never be downloaded again -> you should always assume the user will be coming back at least a second time (and if not, who cares if it took him 50ms more to load your website?!)

Comment: Hmm not really, the JS file will be cached (hopefully), besides, you can always use browser side storage too.

Comment: @Ahmed.. ?! great that you agree with an earlier comment of mine. Having the js in code -> no caching. Having js in a file to load -> caching. 1 file==best, 2files==ok. xFiles==bad. +1files -> initial load slower, then after fast. Btw; Localstorage isn't crossbrowser

Answer (score 1):

TBH I wouldn't do it this way. I would apply the watermarks (or placeholders as they're known) in the HTML, like so:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Hello mum!" />
```

And I would then use jQuery and Moderizer to determine if the current browser supports placeholders or not. If it does, you don't need to worry as the hard work's been done. If it doesn't, you can use a script like this:

```
if ( !Modernizr.input.placeholder )
{
    $( '[placeholder]' ).focus( function()
    {
        var i   = $( this );

        if ( i.val() === i.attr( 'placeholder' ) )
        {
            i.val( '' );
        }
    }).blur( function()
    {
        var i   = $( this );

        if ( i.val() === '' )
        {
            i.val( i.attr( 'placeholder' ) );
        }
    }).blur();
}
```

This script essentially checks to see if the user has clicked into the input or not. If they have, it removes the placeholder as text. If they leave the input and they've left text in there, it doesn't change anything. However, if the input is empty, it then fills it with the placeholder.

I hope that helps.

Comment: the problem is not how to do the watermark thing , I've already done it...the question is only performance question , shall i use one generic javascript file for all my pages or one file for each page?